# Maximum number of infinitely occurring elements in infinite set of pairwise intersecting sets

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose we have infinitely many sets of n elements, with the conditions that (a) no two sets are identical and (b) no two sets have empty intersection. How do we show that there are at most n-1 elements that can occur in infinitely many sets?

Comment: What heave you tried so far?

Comment: Isn't that trivial? If more than $n-1$ elements occured in two $n$-element sets, then these sets are identical. --- Or do you mean that there are at most $n-1$ elements such that each of these individually occurs in infinitely many sets (with a different collection of infiniely many sets for each of the elements)? This would quite clearly be wrong - just consider the set of all $n$-element subsets $A\subset \Bbb N$ with $42\in A$. Then every $n\in \Bbb N$ is contained in infnitely many of the sets.

Comment: @ Gregory I’ve mainly just had a couple of stabs at a reductio assuming it’d violate the uniqueness condition - would be interested to see your counter-example

Comment: @Hagen yes the second interpretation - in your counterexample though you don’t have every pair in A having non-empty intersection

Comment: I deleted my comment because my first counterexample didn't work. I'm trying to salvage it.

Comment: I would recommend including some of the details from your previous attempts in the body of the question and some information on where you got stuck.

Comment: @KeithWynroe In Hagen von Eitzen's counterexample, the sets are pairwise non-disjoint, because 42 is in all of them.

Comment: @Farmer oh duh I completely misread the comment my bad